# WinDBG: How to get the underlying FILE_OBJECT from a WDFFILEOBJECT handle?

Tags: windbg, kmdf, wdf

I'm having a WDFFILEOBJECT handle(0x0000057fedd9b8b8), and I want to know its underlying FILE_OBJECT address, so that I can use `!object xxxx` to query the FILE_OBJECT's `.PointerCount` and `.HandleCount`. What windbg command can I use?

`!wdfkd.wdfhandle 0x0000057fedd9b8b8 f0` does not seems to provide that information.

[image]

Were it a WDFDEVICE handle, I know `!wdfkd.wdfdevice` can tell me the underlying DEVICE_OBJECT, but what about WDFFILEOBJECT?

### ====== SOLVED (many days later) =====

According to snoone's hint, I figured it out. Live information below:

This time, FileObject=**0x0000057fede811b8** .

[image]

I have to use `!wdfkd.handle 0x0000057fede811b8 f0` first, because the handle value 0x0000057fede811b8 is not a valid kernel address, `!wdfkd.handle` tells the real kernel address for the KMDF FxObject behind the handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the dt command specified in the output (dt wdf01000!FxFileObject 0x)